# Opening external link in WebView

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

When I click on a link (let's say: `www.facebook.com`) and I choose my app to open it,  the webview in my app always loads my home page, not the one I clicked on. What could be causing this?

[image: The link]

When I click on it:

[image: It asks me with which one to open]

I choose my browser (unnamed) and then:

[image: Loads home page]

Comment: Could we see how you are trying to open the link in your web view ?

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: @KevinLEGOFF I will post pictures now in EDIT.

Comment: @DevTest I will now with pictures.

Comment: @DevTest Could we see the code of the web view ?

Comment: @KevinLEGOFF MainActivity or XML?

Comment: @KevinLEGOFF
`myWebView.loadUrl("www.google.com");
myWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
view.loadUrl(url);
return true;
}
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you have is that you are opening google.com not the url that it pass to your application via the Intent mechanism.

To get the targeted url you need to parse the data from the intent with this.

`Intent intent = getIntent();
 link = intent.getDataString();
 myWebView.loadUrl(link);`

Comment: You are welecome !